Sound card not working Intel 1135G7, Dell Vostro 3400
After investigation Intel open source firmware files are compressed zst file format, and I could not decompress it as a beginner.


To extract the contents of a compressed .zst file named filename.zst named run the following commands.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zstd
unzstd filename.zst

Short version (because zstd is installed by default in 24.04 and later).
unzstd filename.zst

